# Delphi XE5 Indy: Why message isn't sent?

Tags: delphi, smtp, indy

I have created function for sending mail in my application. The application connects to the server normally but doesn't send message.
The function is following:

```
function TForm1.SendEmail(sendTo, subject, body: string; 
attachFiles: TStringList; smtpHost: string; smtpPort: Integer; smtpUser,
smtpPass: string; tls: TIdUseTLS): boolean;
var
    smtp: TIdSmtp;
    ssl: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    msg: TIdMessage;
    i: Integer;
begin
    smtp:=TIdSmtp.Create(nil);
    ssl:=TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
    msg:=TIdMessage.Create(nil);
    try
        try
            smtp.Host:=smtpHost;
            smtp.Port:=smtpPort;
            smtp.Username:=smtpUser;
            smtp.Password:=smtpPass;

            if not (tls=utNoTLSSupport) then begin
                ssl.Destination:=smtpHost + ':' + IntToStr(smtpPort);
                ssl.Host:=smtpHost;
                ssl.Port:=smtpPort;
                ssl.SSLOptions.Method:=sslvTLSv1;

                smtp.IOHandler:=ssl;
                smtp.UseTLS:=tls;
            end;

            msg.Recipients.EMailAddresses := sendTo;
            msg.Subject:=subject;
            msg.Body.Text:=body;

            if(Assigned(attachFiles)) then begin
                for i := 0 to attachFiles.Count - 1 do begin
                   if FileExists(attachFiles[i]) then
                        TIdAttachmentFile.Create(msg.MessageParts, attachFiles[i]);
                end;
            end;
            smtp.Connect; //Works normally till this line
            smtp.Send(msg); // <-- PROBLEM AT THIS LINE
            smtp.Disconnect;
            result:=true;
        finally
            msg.Free;
            ssl.Free;
            smtp.Free;
        end;
    except
       result:=false;
    end;
end;
```

It connects normally, but doesnt send message. I mentioned it in code by comment.

Comment: What happens instead? If you get an exception, then say so. If you don't get an exception, then look at your network traffic (like with WireShark) to determine whether anything happens there.

Comment: *<-- PROBLEM AT THIS LINE* without a description of what the *PROBLEM* is has no meaning. What specific *PROBLEM* are you having at that line?

Comment: I assume that your mail is blocked by your provider, especially when you send it from a new device. This is what e.g. Google/Gmail does. You need to reduce the security level

Comment: Nothing has happen. I added following code for printing result.
`Memo1.Lines.Add('Connecting...');
            smtp.Connect;
            Memo1.Lines.Add('Sending message...');
            try
              smtp.Send(IdMessage1);//msg);
            except on E:Exception do
              Memo1.Lines.Add(e.Message);
            end;`
last message was **'Sending message...'** and application started waiting and stopped at last.

Comment: The only way `TIdSMTP.Send()` could block like you describe is if either `TIdMessage` is deadlocking while creating the email, or the server is not sending a response back to a command. There is not enough information presented here to diagnose one way or the other. You need to either step into `Send()` with the debugger and find out how far it is actually getting, or at least attach a `TIdLog...` component to the `TIdSMTP.Intercept` property to see what commands/responses are actually being transmitted prior to the blockage. You might also consider setting the `TIdSMTP.ReadTimeout` property.

Comment: It "started waiting" and "stopped at last." To me, that means the program *paused*, and then it finished. That is, at some point the call to `Send` returned to the caller, and then eventually `TForm1.SendEmail` finished running, too. That's not nothing. Anyway, as I said, check your network traffic to find out what, if anything, `Send` wrote to the network. If the `Send` call does not return, then **use the debugger** to find out what it's busy doing.

Comment: @ChristineRoss Lowering security isn't the solution in that case - implementing the required security is (which means generating an application-specific password).

Comment: Saying "Problem at this line" is just like telling your mechanic "I was driving down I-94 at mile marker 64 when the problem happened". Not a diagnosis that would help the mechanic fix your car.

Comment: @Jerry Dodge, here is the example of a blocked acces from unknown device: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzAg0XZupfgTdy1aTFZ6QXRZV2M/view?usp=sharing
unfortunately in german. With the second link you can reduce the security level